# Blackberry SDK 4.2.1 not available in Eclipse Plug-in 1.1

Tags: java, blackberry, sdk, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.5

I need to develop an application for Blackberry Java SDK 4.2.1 and above.
I'm currently under Eclipse Classic 3.5, and I have installed the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.1, with all the Blackberry Java SDK available, versions 4.5 to 5.0.
Unfortunately, there isn't any SDK available under 4.5.
Is anyone know how to solve this problem? I mean, developing for Blackberry Java SDK 4.2.1 with Eclipse IDE.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the RIM JDE for the blackberry version you require, available here: https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=00EC53C4682D36F5C4359F4AE7BD7BA1  It should come with a jar file that you can import as a library.  I think you want the Java Development Environment  v4.2.1.

To include it in Eclipse, I think you can import your project, right click on it in the Navigator/Package Explorer, go to properties, then click "Java Build Path", "Libraries".  Remove the current RIM library, and then click "Add Library".  Choose "UserLibrary", then click "User Libraries" and "New".  Give it a name.  Click "Add Jars", and then navigate to the JAR file that came with the JDE that you downloaded.

Comment: I have installed the Java Development Environment v4.2.1.
I have net_rim_api.jar in the folder located at C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.2.1\lib\.
It is the file you are talking about, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the jar I was speaking about.  Does adding this jar to the build path in eclipse work for you?

Comment: No, it does not...
The project I have to keep working on has been made with a different IDE I think, like Netbeans, and under SDK 4.2.1.
I need to put it under Eclipse with the SDK 4.5... Anyway, sometimes it looks easier to re-develop something.

Answer (score 0):

From the Eclipse menu, you can go in 'Help'->'Install New Software...'. When the dialog opens, put the following address in it: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java and download all you need (just download everything). It takes a while, you it will get there eventually.

Answer (score 0):

i did this just the other day and made a note to self- 
for me, the solution was in the .ee file. you're 3/4 of the way there.

there is a more indepth discussion at RIM:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/JDE-1-1/td-p/480067/page/2;jsessionid=E542E4D3705B364351E21D1E190A70D8